# Retrofit2 MVP Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-mvp

I'm using retrofit on my project and I'm wondering if there's a way to separate the calls to api on different class, for instance : 
Login Activity only /api/users/login
Movies Activity only /api/movies/all
I have all on the same interface and I'm seeing that it's not a good approach... can you guide me how to make it cleaner please? I'm using MVP architecture to do it clean.

This is my `NetworkService.class`

```
public class NetworkService {

    private NetworkAPI networkAPI;
    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
    private LruCache<Class<?>, Observable<?>> apiObservables;

    public NetworkService() {
        this(BASE_URL);
    }

    public NetworkService(String baseUrl) {
        okHttpClient = buildClient();
        apiObservables = new LruCache<>(10);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .create();
        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        // set your desired log level
        //logging.setLevel(Level.BASIC);
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        Builder httpClient = new Builder()
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();

        networkAPI = retrofit.create(NetworkAPI.class);
    }

    /**
     * Method to return the API interface.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public NetworkAPI getAPI() {
        return networkAPI;
    }


    /**
     * Method to build and return an OkHttpClient so we can set/get
     * headers quickly and efficiently.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public OkHttpClient buildClient() {

        Builder builder = new Builder();

        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                // Do anything with response here
                //if we want to grab a specific cookie or something..
                return response;
            }
        });

        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                //this is where we will add whatever we want to our request headers.
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Accept", "application/json").build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });

        return builder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Method to clear the entire cache of observables
     */
    public void clearCache() {
        apiObservables.evictAll();
    }
}
```

And my `NetworkAPI.class` has this

```
public interface NetworkAPI {


    @POST(LOGIN)
    Call<LoginResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
    //And more calls...
}
```

Do you know guys if I can do it cleaner?

Comment: I would really advice you to look on some open source projects. There are thousands of project on GitHub with that. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Make `retrofit` instance singleton then you can create services for login movies like

```
   LoginService login =  retrofit.create(LoginService.class);
   login.login(loginRequest)

   MovieService movie =  retrofit.create(MovieService.class);
   movie.movies(movieRequest)
```

Here is your interface looks like

```
public interface LoginService {


    @POST(LOGIN)
    Call<LoginResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest);
    //And more calls...
}

public interface MovieService {


    @POST(MOVIE)
    Call<MovieResponse> movies(@Body MovieRequest movieRequest);
    //And more calls...
}
```

Comment: How can I change the NetworkService then to make it clean? I got you with the interfaces, it's a good point, but NetworkService is good?

Comment: Also sometimes I see that people make it's own `.addConverterFactory()` should I? what's the purpose of it?

Comment: This is not good. RetrofitBuilder need a base url (which is different for each API interface) you cannot have such a thing like `retrofit instance singleton` unless you  pass complete URL for each API.

Comment: That's purpose is for converting your data possible json to an object. for e.g if you wanna use rxjava you need to use adapter for that for kotlin coroutine you need different adapter

Comment: You don't have a `retrofit` instance singleton, and I also don't know what type and how you create it.

Comment: the base url will be same I think like https://localhost:8080/api/v1/ 
In service class he can add /login or /movie

Comment: What happen if you call another API with different base?, ex: from Stackoverflow? Assume all API has same base URL make your code very fragile

Comment: then he need another retrofit object with that url. or change the url in singleton. But I don't think I ever needed so many api's also using singleton will be much faster then creating Retrofit object in every activity and fragment.

Comment: Yes, that's why you need a singleton RetrofitBuilder, not a singleton Retrofit.

Answer (score 1):

One thing definitely needs to optimize is you should reuse the `OkHttpClient` instead of creating one per API.

Retrofit API creation should also refactored out as a utility class:

```
public class RetrofitFactory {

    private static OkHttpClient baseClient = new Builder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
            // Do anything with response here
            //if we want to grab a specific cookie or something..
            return response;
        }
    }).addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            //this is where we will add whatever we want to our request headers.
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Accept", "application/json").build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }).build();

    private static Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .create();

    private static Retrofit.Builder baseRetrofitBuilder = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson));


    public Builder baseClientBuilder() {
        return baseClient.newBuilder();
    }

    public static <T> T createApi(String url, Class<T> apiClass) {
        return baseRetrofitBuilder.baseUrl(url).build().create(apiClass);
    }

    public static <T> T createApi(String url, Class<T> apiClass, OkHttpClient client) {
        return baseRetrofitBuilder.baseUrl(url).client(client).build().create(apiClass);
    }
}
```

To create NetworkAPI with additional interceptor, you would do:

```
    HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    // set your desired log level
    //logging.setLevel(Level.BASIC);
    logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    OkHttpClient httpClient = RetrofitFactory.baseClientBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .addInterceptor(logging);
    networkApi = RetrofitFactory.createApi(url, NetworkApi.class, httpClient);
```

To create XApi with default setting you do:

```
    xApi = RetrofitFactory.createApi(url, XApi.class);
```

Comment: Ya, but since I'm doing a "clean code" don't you think this isn't a good approach?

Comment: Your code has some problem: OkHttpClient / Gson need to be shared for performance. The code to create API is placed inside the service which is not good (since, ex, if you want to add another common interceptor to all API you should rewrite all other places). Refactor out to RetrofitFactory utility class like mine to make it clean.

Comment: Could you post an example of what you are saying?

Comment: Sorry, but it's good to use static methods? Isn't any other way to do that?

Comment: And everytime I want to do a call like login or get movies I have to call the KttpLogginInterceptor and the OkHttpClient? and then create the networkApi with the retrofitFactory?

Comment: Why do you refrain from static method? Static method is excellently good in programming, since it almost guarantees the behaviour of the method is not changed

Comment: You only create it once in your service. If you need to share it between multiple services class then initialized a static final instance of it and share

Comment: So please, could you tell me for instance where should I call those on Login and Movies?  Or on every presenter I have to do this? one for loginPresenter and another for moviesPresenter?

Comment: If you have a container (like Spring) you could let the container initiailze the instance for you. If you don't have it, then initialize a static instance in that interface: `public interface A { ...your api definition... A instance = RetrofitFactory.createApi(url, A.class); }` And refer it via: A.instance. I hope it is clear now, since it's pretty basic

Comment: What do you mean a container like Spring? if I don't have it I can call that code everytime I want to make a call right?

Comment: Also, I can separate the interface in two? one for login and another for movies? if so how can I call them? because I do not understand this : `xApi = RetrofitFactory.createApi(url, XApi.class);`

Comment: One question what's HttpLoggingInterceptor, could I put it on same class than Retrofit?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could create different interfaces and modify your NetworkService to create the Retrofit adapter depending of the interface that you would like use in different cases.

Let me show you the idea:

**Interfaces:**

```
  public interface LoginInterface { 

        @POST(LOGIN) 
        Call<LoginResponse> login(@Body LoginRequest loginRequest); 
    }

    public interface MovieInterface {

        @GET(MOVIE) 
        Call<MovieResponse> getMovies(); 
    }
```

**NetworkService class**

Here you can see a Singleton for NetworkService and a method create with this method you can create a different interfaces using a singleton instance:

```
public class NetworkService {
    private final String API_BASE_URL = "";

    private static NetworkService INSTANCE = null;
    private static Retrofit retrofit;

    private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;
    private LruCache<Class<?>, Observable<?>> apiObservables;


    public NetworkService() {
        createInstance();
    }

    public static NetworkService getInstance() {

        if(INSTANCE == null){
            return new NetworkService();
        }

        return INSTANCE;
    }

    private void createInstance(){
        okHttpClient = buildClient();
        apiObservables = new LruCache<>(10);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
                .create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .build();


        }

    public static <T> T create(Class<T> apiClass) {
        return retrofit.create(apiClass);
    }

    private OkHttpClient buildClient() {

        HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor = new     HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        loggingInterceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .connectTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
                // Do anything with response here
                //if we want to grab a specific cookie or something..
                return response;
            }
        });

        builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
            @Override
            public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
                //this is where we will add whatever we want to our request headers.
                Request request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Accept", "application/json").build();
                return chain.proceed(request);
            }
        });


        return builder.build();
    }

    /**
     * Method to clear the entire cache of observables
     */
    public void clearCache() {
        apiObservables.evictAll();
    }
}
```

And then you can use instance it using your modified NetworService to instance the interface that you want use:

**NetworService instantiation:**

```
public class LoginActiviy extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

            //Instantiation of LoginInterface
            LoginInterface loginInterface = 
            NetworkService.getInstance().create(LoginInterface.class);
            //Then we use the method for login
            loginInterface.login(/* Handling the callback here*/);

            }
        }

public class MoviesActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_movies);

            //Instantiation of MovieInterface
            MovieInterface movieInterface = 
            NetworkService.getInstance().create(MovieInterface.class);
            //Then we use the method for login
            loginInterface.getMovies(/* Handling the callback here*/);

            }
        }
```

I hope it can help you to get a better idea.

Comment: And what about the NetworkService class? How can I improve it @Juanjo Berenguer?

Comment: Nice! Please, could you explain the difference between your answer and Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn answer please?

Comment: Hello @StuartDTO. The main difference is that i am implementing a Singleton pattern to create the class NetworkService, that means that i am always gonna have a unique instance of this class and i am gonna create the objects in the method **createInstance()** once (the first time when INSTANCE is null). And then we call the method create with the different interfaces needed.